# C# absolute path gets System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to read from a file in C#, VS2017

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"E:‪\prive\Documents\", "test.txt");
string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

So I'm targeting an absolute path, I think.

I get the following error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path 'e:\prive\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\readfile\readfile\bin\Debug\‪\prive\Documents\test.txt'.'

It looks the path is added to the working directory of the vs project.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Arnold

Comment: What do you see if you examine the value of `path` in the debugger?

Comment: value: E:‪\prive\Documents\test.txt

Comment: You have an invisible char after ":"

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening on that second line?

Comment: Solved. When I copied it to answer your question, I rememberd something about hidden char's. Pasted the string in xls and did a char search per position. There was a hidden char between the E and the :. Retyped it manually and it worked.Thanks RandRandom, came to the same conclusion. Thanks itsme for getting me there.

Comment: Really? itsme86's comment the comment after mine where I am mentioning invisible char thats after ":", got you to think about hidden/invisible chars?

Comment: itsme86 asked for the value of the path in his first comment, so I copy pasted it. Thats when the thought occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an invisible character after your ":" try to fix the string, see the following:

[image]

Here is the copy and paste safe string:

```
"E:\prive\Documents\"
```

It is the character:

```
str[2]  8234 '‪'    char
```